# Is there any acknowledged connection between the departure of security officers in The Orville and ST:TNG?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, the-orville

The Orville is quite obviously a take off/spoof of Star Trek (As I described it to my son "as M•A•S•H is to war, The Orville is to Star Trek" - got him interested for about half an episode).

In Star Trek: The Next Generation *Skin of Evil* (S01E22) Tasha Yar, the chief security officer, is killed off and written out of the series.

In The Orville *Home* (S02E03) Alara Kitan, the chief security officer, has an injury that requires her to recuperate on her home world and is written out of the series. (Hand-wavey ignoring the attempt to have her be able to recuperate on board the ship.)

Is there any info that there was an intent to ties these two roles together or that it was planned from early in the series that Halston Sage's role on the show would be limited as Denise Crosby's was?

Comment: So 2 people like the question and 2 dislike it so far. Are the dislikes because the security officer's replacements were totally different characters, therefore I'm an idiot thinking there could be a connection, or is there some other reason it's a bad question?

Comment: I also wondered this, but the answer appears to be a secret.  Can't make this official below answer because it's not backed by official sources, but there is a lot of evidence that this actress and Seth were dating (you can even notice it between the characters on screen if you look close). When they broke up, I imagine it was pretty awkward to work together.  Of course, she also has a role on another show, and it could have caused some schedule conflicts.  I think the fact that they hired another character with the same powers says it didn't have to do with plot. Just an odd STTNG echo.